# Django CRUD operations for multiple records - transaction.atomic vs bulk_create

Tags: django

I have a Django 1.10 model, and a simple model:

I have a simple REST endpoint designed for testing purposes:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
@transaction.atomic
def r_test(request):
    for record in request.data:
        serializer = TestSerializer(data = record)
        if serializer.is_valid():
           serializer.save()
```

...that takes 9 seconds (too slow) to execute for one 100 records.

If I rewrite it the following way, it executes instantly.

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def r_test(request):
    obj_list = []
    for record in request.data:
       obj = Test(field1 = record['field1'])
       obj_list.append(obj)
    Test.objects.bulk_create(obj_list)
```

What bothers me is that I have read in many sources that wrapping function into a transaction (which I do by adding a decorator `@transaction.atomic`) would significantly improve insert operations in case of multiple operations. But I can't see this now.

So the question is, does only bulk_create() deliver super-fast speed for inserting big data, or there's something I am doing wrong with `transaction.atomic`?

**Update:** Moreover, I have `ATOMIC_REQUESTS` set to `True` in my settings. BTW, could it be that something is wrong in the settings? Like, say, Debug = True hinders Django from executing queries in a single transaction ?

**Update 2** I have tried both ways with decorator and by wrapping the for loop in `with transaction.atomic():`. And still I observe instant execution only with `bulk_create()`

**Update 3**. My DB is MySQL

Comment: Probably not the problem but don't you have django_debug_toolbar activated?

Comment: I tried, but I didn't manage to configure it

Comment: Because debug_toolbar rapidly slows down page load in some cases. Especially if SQL option is checked.

Comment: What page do you mean ? This is just a REST endpoint. No page in question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Transactions do generally speed up the inserting process. Since you are already in a transaction due to `ATOMIC_REQUESTS = True`, you won't notice a difference when using `@transaction.atomic()`. The main reason transaction are faster is that committing takes time. Without a transaction, Django uses auto-commit mode, so *every* query results in a commit.

Transactions are not a magic bullet when it comes to performance. You are still performing 100 queries, and 100 roundtrips to the database. Even if your database runs on the same system, that is going to take some time. That's where `bulk_create` comes into play. It performs a single query to insert all the data at once. You've just saved yourself 99 database roundtrips. That is way more significant than any speedup caused by transactions.

Comment: I have to add that if your database is on the same system, 9 seconds for 100 queries is still incredibly slow. If it is on a different system, then network latency can quickly add up.

Comment: No, database is on other system. Thanks for detailed answer

Answer (score 1):

djangorestframework, right? I think you should improve your api function first:

```
def r_test(request):
    serializer = TestSerializer(data=request.data, many=True)
    if serializer.is_valid():
       serializer.save()
```

Try it again.